# Avoiding multiple subqueries in PromQL with offset to get historic averages

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a prometheus server that offers a long retention of 13 months. I want to find anomalies for the number of registrations my web app gets. My idea was to take a look at the number of registrations of the previous weeks as they vary depending on the week day.

To compare my current value across the values of the previous 4 weeks would require me to write 4 subqueries.

**My question:**

Is there an easier way to get the average of a 1h increase of the previous weekdays among the last 4 weeks? To make it clearer I want to get the average of these 4 queries so that I can compare it with my current number of web_registrations.

```
sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 1w))
sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 2w))
sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 3w))
sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 4w))
```

Comment: From what I have seen people are using recording rules for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
(
  sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 1w)) +
  sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 2w)) +
  sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 3w)) +
  sum(increase(web_registrations[1h] offset 4w))
) / 4
```

It will return the average increase for the last hour over the last 4 weeks.

See more details on such query types at https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/23/anomaly-detection-using-prometheus/ .

Comment: That's what I actually ended up with, but since I have 4 more label filters attached to my metric my PromQL query is very long and ugly. Additionally it becomes more ugly if I want to build the average of the past 10 weekdays for instance.

Comment: The repeated parts of the query may be shortened with CTE feature (aka `with templates`) from [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) - see  https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs